# Using applyConstraints(constraints) to change Twilio's LocalVideoTrack resolution of an ongoing video chat

Tags: javascript, constraints, twilio, webrtc, twilio-api

I have tried this code but it is failing, does noting:

```
  const constraints = {
    width: {
      min: 320,

      max: 480
    },
    height: {
      min: 240,

      max: 400
    },
    advanced: [{
        width: 1920,
        height: 1280
      },
      {
        aspectRatio: 1.333
      }
    ]
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true
    })
    .then(mediaStream => {
      const track = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      track.applyConstraints(constraints)
        .then(() => {
          // Do something with the track such as using the Image Capture API.
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
          // The constraints could not be satisfied by the available devices.
        });
    });
```

Any suggestion how to change video resolution of the local video track on the fly when using Twilio's Video Chat API.

Answer (score 2):

If the track is already published you can access the MediaStreamTrack and change the capture constraints.

```js
    const videoTrackPublication = [...room.localParticipant.tracks.values()][0];
    videoTrackPublication._signaling._trackTransceiver.track.applyConstraints({
      width: 640,
      height: 360
    }).catch(e => {
      console.error('Error while applying capture constraints:', e.message);
    });
```

if the track isn't published just pass in the [MediaTrackConstraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints)

```js
    const { createLocalTracks } = require('twilio-video');

    const tracks = await createLocalTracks({
      video: <MediaTrackConstraints>
    });
```

You can read more about [bandwidth consumption](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007485348-Bandwidth-consumption-and-usage-with-Twilio-Programmable-Video-) and [Track Priority and Network Bandwidth Profile API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/video-javascript-sdk-2-0).

[Using the Track Priority API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-track-priority-api) will allow you to change the track priority.

[Network Bandwidth Profile API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/using-bandwidth-profile-api) consumes Track priorities to determine which Tracks are more relevant from the bandwidth allocation perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Cant getting it work:

```
var videoContraints = {
    width: {min: 320, max: 1242, ideal: 1080},
    height: {min: 480, max: 2688, ideal: 1920},
    resizeMode: 'crop-and-scale',
    aspectRatio: 0.5625 // 9:16
};

Video.createLocalVideoTrack({
    video: videoContraints,
}).then(track => {
    localMediaContainer.appendChild(track.attach());
    //
    that.twilioDoctorTrackVideo = track;
});
```

Can do anything, the outputed video is always 640x480

Comment: `createLocalVideoTrack` doesn't need the `video` property, it takes the constraints directly like: `Video.createLocalVideoTrack(videoConstraints)`.